# MySQL query to reference previous field in subqueries

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a question on how to best do this.

I have a table that contains how users are enrolled in a class, say "manual", "db", "email", etc. (enrolment type).

each class has a list of their own class enrolment type with their own ids. For example class A, B, C, etc... have their own enrolment type id's for their class. In other word,s class A's and class B's "db" enrolment type id is different and only for their class use.

So what I want to do is to first look up all class enrolments with a certain type, say "db" (id=88) for each class and use that output to feed into another query that shows what their enrolment type id is for "manual" (id=123) associated with that class. Then the last query would update statement to change the enrolment type to what we want to "manual" instead of "DB".

How can that be done in subqueries? I've written them but as a scripting language in PHP to use their loop function but I want to try and learn to write it as a nested subqueries to accomplish the same in MySQL.

Table:

***class***

```
classid | name | start date |... etc.

1 | ..
2 | ..
3 | ..
4 | ..
```

***class_enrolment***

```
classid | userid | role | enroltypeid |.. etc
1 | 1234 | student | 40 | ..
1 | 5678 | student | 40 | ..
1 | 9012 | student | 40 | ..
1 | 3456 | student | 40 | ..
1 | 7890 | student | 40 | ..
1 | 7521 | instructor | 40 | ..
```

***class_enroltype***

```
classid | enrolid | enrolname | etc.
1 | 39 | manual | ..
1 | 40 | db | ..
1 | 41 | ldap | ...
1 | 42 | email | ...
....
34 | 897 | manual | ..
34 | 898 | db | ...
34 | 899 | ldap |...
34 | 900 | email | ...
...
1045 | 6234 | manual | ..
1045 | 6235 | db | ...
1045 | 6236 | ldap |...
1045 | 6237 | email | ...
```

In the above example for classid number 1, I want to change their enroltypeid from "40" to "39" and the same logic for all other enrolments in other respective classes ("db" to "manual" enrolment type).

thoughts?

thanks!

Comment: Do not tell us how you decide to solve. Publist the task itself. And do not show approximate structures and partial values. Show simplified, but adequate, `CREATE TABLE`, some sample data in `INSERT INTO` form (the best way - create fiddle) and desured result for this data.

Comment: that is why I am asking for help

Comment: But you have not explained the task clear enough, and you give no the model for testing.

Comment: Provide table structures as DDL (`SHOW CREATE TABLE foo\G;`), + your data as `INSERT INTO foo VALUES (...);` - you can't expect us to type that all out manually! Plus, there's the risk of errors. There are a few articles on how to ask questions here on my profile - you might want to take a look? You could also do this as a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=bb5c1d9f8e335c86d596672f1e4b37c7). You also haven't told us which version of MySQL - this is **very important** as MySQL has had several critical features added relatively recently! p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)